# Random iOS CloudKit crashes during development

Tags: ios, cloudkit

My app uses CloudKit and includes the following line of very basic of code:

```
    self.cloudContainer = CKContainer.defaultContainer()
```

During development and debugging with Xcode, it will randomly crash on that line of code with the following exception:

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CKException', reason: 'The application is missing required entitlement com.apple.developer.icloud-services'

If I just run it again from Xcode with no changes, it may run fine or it will crash again.

I've filed a radar on the problem and, as requested by Apple, sent them my .entitlements file and crash logs. They've said the entitlements look fine but no response on a solution or workaround.

Has anyone else seen this or have a suggestion to get around it? It really makes CloudKit development difficult.

Comment: I'm having this same problem for maybe over a year or so. Using Xcode 9.3.

Comment: was the crash on iOS 9.2? it's a headache i found no cure.

Comment: Any luck figuring this out?